# How to search(matchings) more than one values in an php array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

In php we have array_search() to search a value in an array. According to my knowledge it can search only one value at a time. How to search more that one values in an array. Are there any functions to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a function for it, but you could do that in a foreach loop quite easily.

```
<?php

$array('some', 'values', 'here');
$values = array('values', 'to', 'find');

foreach($values as $v) {
  $key = array_search($v, $array):
  if ($key) {
    $new_array[] = $array[$key];
  }
}

?
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array = array('some', 'values', 'here');
$values = array('values', 'to', 'find');

foreach($values as $v) {
  $key = array_search($v, $array);
  if ($key) {
    $new_array[] = $array[$key];
  }
}
```